# Стилизация элемента через js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я создаю модальное окно через JS

```
const modal = document.createElement('div');
```

Стилизовать его нужно через JS, стилизую стандартным образом:

```
modal.style.width = '100%';
modal.style.height = '100px';
// И так далее
```

Но задавать стили таким образом довольно долго и громоздко по коду, следовательно вопрос: возможно ли через JS стилизовать элемент другим образом(например, через объект или что-то подобное)?

Comment: Создаёте класс и при создании элемента указывайте класс.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev стОит пояснить, что класс в CSS со стилями)) а то товарищ ещё подумает что класс в JS))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский действительно, не подумал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[вариант 1](https://learn.javascript.ru/styles-and-classes)

```
div.style.cssText=`color: red !important;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  `;
```

[вариант 2](https://coderoad.ru/3968593/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-CSS-%D0%B2-JavaScript)

```
document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute(
   "style", "font-size: 100px; font-style: italic; color:#ff0000;");
```